# JBoss AS 6.1.0.Final suffers from overdone debug logging created by pdfox (PDFStreamEngine)

Tags: log4j, pdfbox, jboss6.x, apache-commons-logging

When I'm performing this line in my class:

```
pages.get(i).convertToImage(IMAGE_TYPE, RESOLUTION);
```

... I receive a lot of the following messages:

```
2014-06-11 17:01:42,476 DEBUG [org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10) processing substream token: PDFOperator{Tj}
2014-06-11 17:01:42,494 DEBUG [org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10) processing substream token: PDFOperator{ET}
2014-06-11 17:01:42,494 DEBUG [org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10) processing substream token: PDFOperator{Q}
```

Nevertheless, the root logger in my jboss-logging.xml has been put to **INFO**. When I explicitly put this in my XML config:

```
<logger category="org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine">
    <level name="INFO"/>
</logger>
```

... it is still putting DEBUG statements in my LOG file.

Any help?

Comment: Try this answer, it shows a different syntax than the one you are using: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3475120/535646

Comment: Thanks! By adding the appender-ref, the problem is solved! How can I accept your answer?

Comment: You can upvote the comment. I didn't take the time to write an answer, because I wasn't THAT sure :-)

Comment: Thanks. I've just noticed it's not completely working. After the change you suggested, I have no logging at all ... from not a single component. Sorry, it's still not fixed ... :-(

Comment: maybe add "log4j" as a tag, to attract the log4j specialists. I came here because of the pdfbox tag. I use log4j myself, but not with the xml config.

Comment: Thanks for tip! Added the tag log4J