# Log4j logging twice with different formats

Tags: java, log4j

I can't figure out why log4j is appending twice with different formats.  Anyone come across this before?

Here is my log4j.xml file:

```
<log4j:configuration>

    <appender name="async" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <!-- this parameter need to be set to false to avoid application from hanging. -->
        <param name="Blocking" value="false" />
        <appender-ref ref="myAppender" />
    </appender>

    <appender name="myAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d{ISO8601} [%t] %c %x - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.server">
        <level value="INFO" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="INFO" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException" additivity="false">
       <level value="off" />
       <appender-ref ref="async" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="net.sf.ehcache">
        <level value="INFO" />
    </logger>

     <logger name="com.mchange">
         <level value="INFO" />
     </logger>

     <root>
         <priority value="INFO" />
         <appender-ref ref="async" />
     </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

And here is some sample output:

```
INFO  2016-08-26 11:01:38,353 [main] com.server.Server  - Server started successfully...
11:01:38,353 INFO :  Server started successfully...
```

EDIT: When I change the "myAppender" appender threshold to "ERROR", the second log message shown (The one starting with the time, not "INFO") is still being generated.  Is there some default logger that I need to disable?  It seems that something is still logging those "INFO" level messages, even though the specified appender is for "ERROR" level messages.  Also, if I comment out the entire log4j.xml file, the second log message (and all like it) are still being logged.  How can I prevent this?  Thanks!

Comment: I think that's because you are using 2 appenders for the same thing. Try commenting out the "async" appender and change root child to `<appender-ref ref="myAppender" />`

Comment: Doesn't help, same duplicated output is generated

Comment: try commenting out the full logger with `name="org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException"`

Comment: Same problem happening

Comment: hum, then I would recommend you to comment out all the loggers and appenders and add one by one from the root

Comment: doesn't help.  even with just the console appender and no loggers, there is still the duplicated output.  And besides, the second log statement has a format that is not specified anywhere, so I don't know why that one is showing up

Comment: Don't confuse your app logging with your app server output. Not sure what app server you are using but for jboss the log output is on server.log, you should check that the content is not repeated in that file. However, the console is a different stuff since it's the standard output for your app and the app server as well

Comment: It's a jar file, not an app server

Comment: Try changing myAppender so that it logs to a file. My guess is that you will get the first line in the file and the second will still show up in the console. In that case something else (not Log4j) is writing to the console. Perhaps using another logging framework. Hard to say without knowing more about your application.

Comment: Have you checked if any of your dependencies are pulling in log4j config of their own?

Comment: Is this com.server.Server class a class our yours? When it is from a library it is most likely it is bringing its own logging configuration as the logging pattern differs from the one you are defining. Then just have a look inside the jar file and search for a logging configuration and have a look in the (decompiled) Server class.

Comment: Yeah com.server.Server is mine, would there be a way to exclude all other logging configs that are not mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I had to do:

```
<logger name="com.server" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="async" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with XML syntax of log4j (I use log4j.properties for configuration) so here are my 2 cents to try to help you debug and fix the code.

Firstly try using below root logger configuration instead of yours `<appender-ref ref="async" />` -

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException" additivity="false">
   <level value="off" />
   <appender-ref ref="myAppender" />
</logger>
..............
...........
 <root>
     <priority value="INFO" />
     <appender-ref ref="myAppender" />
 </root>
```

If above doesn't work then, try putting `<param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />` both in `async` and `myAppender`, and I guess no `Server started successfully` log will be printed (I think you have already tried with `myAppender`)

If this helps then it means the way you are trying to reference/inherit the logger isn't working or using correctly, so you have think from that direction and correct the issue, you need to read more about `appender-ref` element and `AsyncAppender` logger.

Whether above works or not, I am guessing that you are trying to achieve following -

1. Print on your standard input/output i.e. your terminal window
2. Print in file as well for prod environment

I would do this in log4j.properties as follow:

```
log4j.logger.com.sks.cs50=DEBUG, CS50GlobalFileAppender, stdout

#####CS50 Web log##########
log4j.appender.CS50GlobalFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CS50GlobalFileAppender.File=${logDir}cs50.log
log4j.appender.CS50GlobalFileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=50
log4j.appender.CS50GlobalFileAppender.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.CS50GlobalFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CS50GlobalFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%C %d [%t] [%X{randomNumber}] %-5p - %m%n
log4j.appender.CS50GlobalFileAppender.MaxFileSize=500000KB

# Log format to standard output
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%X{randomNumber}] %-5p - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache = INFO
log4j.logger.com.sun = INFO
log4j.logger.sun = INFO
log4j.logger.javax.xml.bind = INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework = INFO
log4j.logger.com.cgi = DEBUG
```

So, I guess you can do something as below.

```
<log4j:configuration>

    <appender name="async" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <!-- this parameter need to be set to false to avoid application from hanging. -->
        <param name="Blocking" value="false" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d{ISO8601} [%t] %c %x - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="myAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d{ISO8601} [%t] %c %x - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.server">
        <level value="INFO" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="INFO" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException" additivity="false">
       <level value="off" />
       <appender-ref ref="async" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="net.sf.ehcache">
        <level value="INFO" />
    </logger>

     <logger name="com.mchange">
         <level value="INFO" />
     </logger>

     <root>
         <priority value="INFO" />
         <appender-ref ref="async" />
         <appender-ref ref="myAppender" />
     </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

**Please note** that above XML configuration is with assumption that `org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender` prints in some log file, but if it doesn't (which I am guessing that it doesn't) then above will not work (you can still use above XML configuration to achieve file + console logging if you replace `AsyncAppender` with a `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`) and I would wonder why you are just can't use `org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender` directly because it already prints to console, so may be just use:

```
<appender name="async" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
<!-- this parameter need to be set to false to avoid application from hanging. -->
    <param name="Blocking" value="false" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d{ISO8601} [%t] %c %x - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: have tried with all combinations of appenders, still gets duplicated

Comment: @holtc: Ah, quite strange, what did you get when you used `<param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />` for both "async" and "myAppender" logger ??

Comment: my stuff didn't log (b/c no errors), but the other 3rd party jars still logged

Comment: May be you have to look for more options, can you check if you have some other log4j configuration file in the class path, or can you try to use no logger in your `<root>`, may be you have start from nothing i.e. no logging and then try moving upwards ..

Comment: There's a bunch of dependencies pulled in, so maybe there is config stuff coming from there.  Is there any way to ignore all config files except for mine?

Comment: Because of dependency you should not get the loggers from this package `com.server` because if I am correct then this is you own package .. In which application server you are running your application .. Do one thing - use `Dlog4j.configuration` property to explicitly define your log4j configuration file .. I do like this in my windows box - `set JAVA_PROPERTIES=%JAVA_PROPERTIES% -Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:\dev\wls12120\user_projects\domains\mydomain\tmiConfig\log4j.properties`

Comment: If by using `<param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />` in both loggers you do not see any `Server started successfully...` log then it means something is wrong there .. Try this also - set `<param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />` for "myAppender" logger and you should see only `11:01:38,353 INFO :  Server started successfully...` and then remove it for "myAppender" and set for "async" and then you should see only `INFO  2016-08-26 11:01:38,353 [main] com.server.Server  - Server started successfully...` .. If this happens then I think certainly both your configurations are taking effect ..

Answer (score 2):

***why Log4j logging twice?***

- `Log4j` logs to all loggers in the hierarchy unless you ask it not
     to ( by setting `additivity` to `false` ), so you are seeing output
     from your `com.server` logger and the default `ROOT` logger which
     always exists.

**solution for above problem**

- This is happening, because you have not defined the 
  **additivity="false"** attribute on your **com.server** logger. now i fixed it, you can try.

  ```
  <appender name="async" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
  <!-- this parameter need to be set to false to avoid application from hanging. -->
      <param name="Blocking" value="false" />
      <appender-ref ref="myAppender" />
  </appender>

  <appender name="myAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d{ISO8601} [%t] %c %x - %m%n" />
      </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.server" additivity="false">
      <level value="INFO" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.springframework">
      <level value="INFO" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException" additivity="false">
     <level value="off" />
     <appender-ref ref="async" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="net.sf.ehcache">
      <level value="INFO" />
  </logger>

   <logger name="com.mchange">
       <level value="INFO" />
   </logger>

   <root>
       <priority value="INFO" />
       <appender-ref ref="async" />
   </root>
  ```

Comment: I have tried that, then nothing from my server gets logged

Comment: @holtc, are you not able to get log for `Root` as i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: if the above answer not work, i would like to suggest [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3475120/5813861)

Comment: the root appender works, as stated if any logs come from my server, they are duplicated, even in the simplest form of the configuration

Comment: This doesn't log anything because the `com.server` has no appender.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that somewhere in your application another appender is added programmatically, maybe like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;

public class Application {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //log.setAdditivity(false);
        ConsoleAppender ca = new ConsoleAppender();
        ca.setWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        ca.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%-5p [%t]: %m%n"));
        log.addAppender(ca);
        log.info("Hello world");
        log.info("Bye world");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

This in addition to a *log4j.xml* or *log4j.properties* file found on the classpath causes the effect you see in your logs.

---

**Update:** Or maybe even something like `Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(ca)` gets called, affecting the root logger and not just a sepecific one.

Using your config file for me this yields the following log output:

```
INFO  [main]: Hello world
INFO  [main]: Bye world
INFO  2016-09-04 13:48:25,887 [main] de.scrum_master.app.Application  - Hello world
INFO  2016-09-04 13:48:25,889 [main] de.scrum_master.app.Application  - Bye world
```

Comment: have looked thru the code, no appender is being added programatically

Comment: Then probably a third party tool, an internal library or the container does it. If you can make the problem reproduceable with a minimal configuration sample and details about the container, I guess someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There have been some answers already so I just went ahead and created a program to prove that this indeed works unless there is some problem in your code - See my two simple classes below and try to find out the difference between these and yours.

```
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

import com.server.Test;

public class MyListener {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DOMConfigurator.configure("/home/sanjeevd/depot/bas/projects/xxx.1/yyy/src/log4j.xml");

    Test test = new Test();
}
```

}

```
package com.server;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Test {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

public Test() {
    logger.info("PRINTTTTTTTTTTTT");
}
```

}

Also add these two lines on the top of your log4j.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
```

Having said this, I'm mostly sure that there is some other logger getting initialized or there are more than one lo4j.xml in your application etc. Please note, I didn't change anything in your log4j.xml other than adding headers.

The output is below (and it prints just onces) -

```
INFO  2016-09-06 10:57:37,506 [main] com.server.Test  - PRINTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

Another thing you should do is to set "system property" for bootstrap debugging to see what's going on at log4j level i.e. put

```
System.setProperty("log4j.debug", "true");
```

just before configuring log4j. If you are deploying it onto some servlet container (tomcat etc) then pass -Dlog4j.debug=true parameter during startup.

The output in my case was -

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@42a57993.
log4j: Using URL [file:/home/sanjeevd/depot/bas/projects/xxx.1/yyy/bin/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
log4j: debug attribute= "null".
log4j: Ignoring debug attribute.
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [com.server] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for com.server is  [INFO].
log4j: com.server level set to INFO
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.springframework] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.springframework is  [INFO].
log4j: org.springframework level set to INFO
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException] additivity to [false].
log4j: Level value for org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException is  [off].
log4j: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException level set to OFF
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender]
log4j: Attaching appender named [myAppender] to appender named [async].
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [INFO].
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.out].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%-5p %d{ISO8601} [%t] %c %x - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [async] to category [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException].
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [net.sf.ehcache] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for net.sf.ehcache is  [INFO].
log4j: net.sf.ehcache level set to INFO
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [com.mchange] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for com.mchange is  [INFO].
log4j: com.mchange level set to INFO
log4j: Level value for root is  [INFO].
log4j: root level set to INFO
log4j: Adding appender named [async] to category [root].
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
log4j: debug attribute= "null".
log4j: Ignoring debug attribute.
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [com.server] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for com.server is  [INFO].
log4j: com.server level set to INFO
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.springframework] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.springframework is  [INFO].
log4j: org.springframework level set to INFO
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException] additivity to [false].
log4j: Level value for org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException is  [off].
log4j: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException level set to OFF
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender]
log4j: Attaching appender named [myAppender] to appender named [async].
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [INFO].
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.out].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%-5p %d{ISO8601} [%t] %c %x - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [async] to category [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException].
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [net.sf.ehcache] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for net.sf.ehcache is  [INFO].
log4j: net.sf.ehcache level set to INFO
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [com.mchange] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for com.mchange is  [INFO].
log4j: com.mchange level set to INFO
log4j: Level value for root is  [INFO].
log4j: root level set to INFO
log4j: Adding appender named [async] to category [root].
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding **additivity="false"** to your **com.server** logger will solve the issue.

```
    <logger name="com.server" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
    </logger>
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity

Comment: I have tried that, then nothing from my server gets logged

Comment: This would mean there is no appender for this logger. No appender means nothing appended to any log destination.